# google maps v3: can you set a map by bounds only?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

With just the SW and NE coordinates, can you set a google maps view, or are zoom and/or a center coordinate mandatory?

I've been looking and 
a) can't find a definitive answer.
b) any constructs that i have tried dont work.

If anyone knows that it is possible, how would i go about defining the bounds options to create the map?

Thanks!

Comment: Given you have both bounding corners of the display area can't you just find the center point using math and set it to that?

Comment: > any constructs that i have tried dont work.

What *have* you tried?

Comment: sure - getting the center point is easy, but working out the appropriate zoom level isn't (as far as i can see - maybe it is!)..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `fitBounds` to set the map to (approximately) the specified bounds, as described in the [API reference](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Map).

Comment: thanks Jim - it's not *quite* what we were looking for, but i think it's as close as we're going to be able to get.