# Unable to display 3 map types in Google Maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am new to Google Maps.
I want to display Google maps with three different map types(map,satellite,Hybrid) in the map.

For that I am writing code like

```
function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(35.02, 111.02),
    zoom: 8, mapTypeControlOptions: {
  mapTypeIds: [google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP, google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE,google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID]
    },
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
  };
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);
```

But with the above code I am able to display only Map and satellite map types in the map. the third map type hybrid is not displaying in the map.
Also when I click on the type satellite I am getting an option like Label . So I don't want to display the label option under satellite.

Comment: it's off-topic, but remove the trailing comma here which will throw an error in IE: `mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,`

Answer (score 8):

Maps v3 will always condense the four available mapTypeIds (HYBRID, ROADMAP, SATELLITE, TERRAIN)  into two buttons plus a checkbox for each of these buttons. So
SATELLITE + HYBRID will give you a *Satellite* button with a *Labels* checkbox and ROADMAP + TERRAIN will give you a *Map* button with a *Terrain* checkbox.

Please note that the checkbox is only shown when you hover over an **active** button, so you will have to be in *Map* mode to see the *Terrain* checkbox under the button and you must be in *Satellite* mode to see the *Labels* checkbox!

It is interresting to see that there actually **is** a Hybrid button, but it only becomes visible when you add HYBRID to the mapTypeIds **without** adding SATELLITE. The same is true for the Terrain button, which only becomes visible when you add TERRAIN to the list, but **not** ROADMAP.

Switching the mapTypeControlOptions.style to a dropdown box (DROPDOWN_MENU) instead of buttons (HORIZONTAL_BAR) will also not reveal more than two items in the resulting dropdown box. Just like the buttons there will be a maximum of two dropdown items plus a checkbox for each of them.

Comment: ... PLUS your custom style(s) if you create them.

Answer (score 5):

looks like you can have only 2 of the 4 `MapTypeId` labels on your map.

but you can can force the map to `hybrid` by setting

```
map.setMapTypeId(google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID)
```

at any time, be it the user clicking a link, a button, a timmer, at the end of your code, etc.

check this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/RASG/vDLfs/

[image: ddd]

---

i just discovered something new on a google group.

when you add `google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID` to `mapTypeIds`, and you already have `google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE`, instead of showing both options google maps now add an option called "labels" when you mouseover "satellite".

the effect is the same as having the "hybrid" option in v2.

check the updated jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/RASG/vDLfs/6/

[image: eee]

Comment: Thanks for your reply.. i too got the solution like the one you mentioned. But my clients wants to display it inside the map.
they have used  version2  where they were able to make it inside the map. now they want to upgrade it to version 3

Comment: @krishnasavith you're welcome. spread the news to your client :)

Comment: Dude also is it mandatory to give zoom option ? 
without that map is not getting displayed.

Comment: @krishnasavith http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11399557/google-maps-v3-can-you-set-a-map-by-bounds-only

Answer (score 0):

Adding a Google Earth map type to the display disables the TERRAIN option under ROADMAP and the HYBRID option under SATELLITE.